# Compute the closest distance between an input matrix with two others using matlab

Tags: matrix, matlab

If we consider 3 variables : x=1; y=2; and z=3;
To know if x is more closer to y than z , we must perform the following computations :

```
a=x-y;   % -1
a=a.^2;  % (-1).^2 = 1
b=x-z;   %-2
b=b.^2;  % (-2).^2 =4
%find the minimum
d=min(a,b);  % 1
```

Therefore, we notice that x is more closer to y than z.

Now, let us consider 3 matrices x,y and z instead of variables. It is the same concept but i am working with matrices instead of variables. 
Recall that i want to know if x is more closer to y or to z.

By the way, i tried to write the following matlab code:

```
  clear all;
close all;
clc;

%I have 3 matrices x, y and z
x=[1 4 1 ; 4 5 3 ; 7 3 9]
y=[3 6 5 ; 6 5 7 ; 3 2 3]
z=[2 6 5 ; 3 7 6 ; 2 7 6]

%Compute the distance between x and y
a= x-y;
%squaring this distance
a_squared=a.^2;

%Compute the distance between x and z
b=x-z;
%squaring the distance
b_squared=b.^2;

%So to compute the closest distance among a_squared and b_squared, i think
%that i should compute the minimum.

d=min(a_squared,b_squared); % in this case, we get a new matrix which is the minimum. So how can i know if this d belongs to the cluster y or z ?
```

in this case, we get a new matrix which is the minimum. So how can i know if this d belongs to the cluster y or z ? So regarding the value of d, how to know if d belongs to y or z ? In other words, how can i know if x is more closer to y or to z ?? Please i need your help and opinions. Any help will be very appreciated.

Thank's in advance.

Comment: This Q&A -- http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/507742/distance-similarity-between-two-matrices -- may be of interest to you

Comment: Your question is equivalent to the question of what distance between matrices you consider. For example, take a look at [this post](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/507742/distance-similarity-between-two-matrices). Once you have selected one, you have to implement it, and it's done :).

Comment: Thank you for your answers :) , so the distance computed in this link will be an integer value or a matrix ? If it is an integer value, so this will be a great answer and solution to me :) . Please i need your responses :)

Comment: And please can you write me in an answer the matlab code of at least two of the methods of distances . for example for d1, d2 written in this helpful link..

Comment: @Christina, not an integer, but a *scalar*, in this case a real number.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A distance can be defined as the [norm of a difference](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Distance#Distance_in_Euclidean_space).

For distances of matrices, you can define several distances depending on which [matrix norm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Matrix_norm) you use. Matlab's [`norm`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/norm.html) function can compute different norms, including the 2-norm and the Frobenius norm.

I'd recommend you start with the 2-norm and see whether this helps you do what you want to do.

Example code: Distance between matrices `x` and `y`:

```
dxy = norm(x - y, 2);
```

Comment: You select them via the second argument of `norm`. See http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/norm.html

Comment: so the frobenius norm is also called 2-norm ? (does frobenius is the same of euclidean?)

Comment: so we have : norm (x-y,1) or norm (x-y,2) or norm (x-y, 'fro') . so the 2-norm is different from frobenius. And we have also the infinity norm. True ?

Comment: Well, I assumed so, but I confused the 2-norm of a vector with that of a matrix. I corrected my answer. The 2-norm of a matrix is actually the largest 2-norm of a vector that arises from a projection of the matrix, or, the largest singular value of the matrix. The Frobenius norm is the naive generalization, just treat the matrix as a vector and compute *its* 2-norm.

Comment: Correct, for a matrix we habe 1-norm, 2-norm, Inf-norm, and Frobenius norm.

Comment: exactly, now your answer seems perfect to me :) thank you, +1

Comment: :) Hope it does what you need.

Comment: Yes :), but before we finish, the 2-norm is similar to the euclidean true ?

Comment: If you use the vector 2-norm to define a vector (or point) distance, this is identical to the Euclidean distance. The matrix 2-norm is the generalization of the vector 2-norm to matrices, so in this sense it is similar to the Euclidean.

Comment: There is a numerical example in the documentation. It also explains the computation, it is simply `max(svd(X))`. Computing the SVD is not simple however, so I'm afraid I can't give an example that makes it clearer. It is not as straightforward as the Frobenius norm.

Comment: Exactly, i am reading this link: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Singular_value_decomposition ,, and i notice that the computation is not straightforward. So i can just know that it is max(svd(X))